# How to update Nodes within a random manner in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

how can i update a random set of nodes in Neo4j.  I tried the folowing:

```
match (Firstgraph)
with id(Firstgraph) as Id
return Firstgraph.name, Firstgraph.version,id(Firstgraph)
order by rand();
match (G1:FirstGraph)
where id(G1)=Id
set G1.Version=5
```

My idea is the get a random set then update it, but i got the error:

`Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 2`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out what's the problem here, first of all, your error

> Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 2

This is coming from your query, if we check it, we see that you did two queries in the same sentence, that's why you get this error.

```
match (Firstgraph) with id(Firstgraph) as Id 
return Firstgraph.name, Firstgraph.version,id(Firstgraph) order by
rand(); match (G1:FirstGraph) where id(G1)=Id set G1.Version=5
```

This is not a good query, because you can't use `;` in a query sentence, it's the query end marker, so you can't do another query after this, but you can use `UNION`:

```
match (Firstgraph) with id(Firstgraph) as Id 
return 
    Firstgraph.name, Firstgraph.version,id(Firstgraph) order by rand() 
UNION 
match (G1:FirstGraph) where id(G1)=Id set G1.Version=5
```

Also, if you want to match a random set of nodes, you can simply do this (this example is for a 50% chances to get each node):

```
Match (node) Where rand() > 0.5 return node
```

And then do whatever you want with the node using `WITH`

Comment: Thank you very much Supamiu for your help. The last manner is very usefull: Match (node) Where rand() > 0.5 return node.